# Passing object (interface) without writing keys

Tags: typescript

To put it simple, I have an interface A:

`interface A { names: string[]; nr: number; }`

And I can pass/create an A object so:

`{ names: ['John'], nr: 11 }`

However, how could I pass it without writing the keys, so like below:

`{ ['John'], 11 }`

Is it possible in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for a tuple type:

```js
type A = [name: string[], nr: number];

const example: A = [['John'], 11];
```

Here's an example [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaA7AhgWwgLigZ2ACcBLFAcyQF0AaKFQ3FAVwwCMJDKBuAKB4GMA9igJQIAD0xgANjlgJkSAOQApQQAsUSmlACMu7kA).

**Edit:** keyed arrays aren't really a thing in TS/JS, but perhaps you could use a function to get the desired results?

```
interface A { names: string[]; nr: number; }

function makeA (names: A["names"], nr: A["nr"]): A {
    return { names, nr };
}

const a: A = makeA(['John'], 11);

console.log(a.name, a.nr);
```

Here's the [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7JHAthAZwC5kCwpQBzAbQF0BubKEkAV1wCNpGBfAKD4xWIBGGAB7EMlxwA1hHQAKHPmJpqAIhWENtADRMSqTSCi6AlEcx9kt5FAhhWUKVm0EDp5D3p9+fBEkyZDgrAF5pOQVFagByAClxAAsQWP1kAEYM83ogA).

Comment: It works fine, however I cannot use it like: object.nr etc. I would like still to have this possibility.

Comment: I updated with a factory function pattern that may get a bit closer to your desired behavior.